# How to get all messages\errors returned by a Stored Proc

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, sqlexception

I have a strored Proc which, when called with a specific set to parameters, returns following messages -

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "abc" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "pqr" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "xyz" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Name'.
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ErrorHandlerProc, Line 218
Error Processing Request [ApplicationError]
```

I am interested in the last line of error since that is the one which is to be show to the user

```
Error Processing Request [ApplicationError]
```

However when I catc SqlExceltion, the message property only contains the first line i.e.

```
The multi-part identifier "abc" could not be bound.
```

How can I get the complete error and show that to user.

Please note that I cannot change the stored proc.

**Update**

The `SqlException.Errors` collection contains only one entry which is the first line returned by the sp. The `InnerException` is null and other properties such as `Data` or `StackTrace` do not return required information.

Comment: can you show your code and your try/catch? check properties of the exception object in the catch, like stacktrace and InnerException

Comment: You should never have those kinds of errors in a sp that has been debugged. Those have to do with bad syntax which should be fixed long before the user ever sees.

Comment: @HLGEM - agreed. But sometimes all you can do is work with what you have got :).

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Errors`-property of the `SqlException`. There you should find a list of `SqlError` Objects with all the messages from the underlying provider.

Comment: please see the updates in the question. The Errors collection does not contain requierd information.